# Можно ли получить логин уч. записи человека который подключился к веб-приложению по локальной сети?(Java)

Tags: java

Вопрос возможно не совсем корректен, но  суть такая: на сервере лежит веб приложение по которому все ПК в локальной сети могут подключиться к этому приложению введя в браузере некоторыйIP/"веб приложение", в программе забито так что username берется с того ПК где лежит приложение в данном случае командой

> System.getenv("USERNAME");

А можно ли получить логин того кто подключается к веб приложению?

Comment: приложение без авторизации?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Да, приложение без авторизации, понятно, что можно форму авторизации сделать, но для меня это не нужно

Comment: насколько мне известно это можно сделать только в ie из коробки, т.к. браузер как-то должен узнать этот username чтобы передать его на сервер

Comment: Из вопроса не понятно какой уровень влияния на приложение у Вас имеется. Вы спрашиваете о возможных решениях на уровне изменения кода, либо на уровне изменения сетевой инфраструктуры?

Comment: @AlexeyR. Я разработчик этого приложения, доступ к коду есть

Comment: Думаю, Вам надо копать в сторону Керберос.

Answer (score 0):

Из веб приложения можно получить список переменных среды через:

```
Map<String, String> env=System.getenv();
```

[документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv())

Для Windows вы получите такой список:

```
VARIABLE    WINDOWS 10
----------------------
%ALLUSERSPROFILE%   C:\ProgramData
%APPDATA%   C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming
%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%    C:\Program Files\Common Files
%COMMONPROGRAMFILES(x86)%   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
%CommonProgramW6432%    C:\Program Files\Common Files
%COMSPEC%   C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
%HOMEDRIVE% C:\
%HOMEPATH%  C:\Users\{username}
%LOCALAPPDATA%  C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local
%LOGONSERVER%   \\{domain_logon_server}
%PATH%  C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
%PathExt%   .com;.exe;.bat;.cmd;.vbs;.vbe;.js;.jse;.wsf;.wsh;.msc
%PROGRAMDATA%   C:\ProgramData
%PROGRAMFILES%  C:\Program Files
%ProgramW6432%  C:\Program Files
%PROGRAMFILES(X86)% C:\Program Files (x86)
%PROMPT%    $P$G
%SystemDrive%   C:
%SystemRoot%    C:\Windows
%TEMP%  C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp
%TMP%   C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp
%USERDOMAIN%    Userdomain associated with current user.
%USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE% Userdomain associated with roaming profile.
%USERNAME%  {username}
%USERPROFILE%   C:\Users\{username}
%WINDIR%    C:\Windows
%PUBLIC%    C:\Users\Public
%PSModulePath%  %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
%OneDrive%  C:\Users\{username}\OneDrive
%DriverData%    C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
%CD%    Outputs current directory path. (Command Prompt.)
%CMDCMDLINE%    Outputs command line used to launch current Command Prompt session. (Command Prompt.)
%CMDEXTVERSION% Outputs the number of current command processor extensions. (Command Prompt.)
%COMPUTERNAME%  Outputs the system name.
%DATE%  Outputs current date. (Command Prompt.)
%TIME%  Outputs time. (Command Prompt.)
%ERRORLEVEL%    Outputs the number of defining exit status of previous command. (Command Prompt.)
%PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER%  Outputs processor identifier.
%PROCESSOR_LEVEL%   Outputs processor level.
%PROCESSOR_REVISION%    Outputs processor revision.
%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%  Outputs the number of physical and virtual cores.
%RANDOM%    Outputs random number from 0 through 32767.
%OS%    Windows_NT
```

Если все юзеры в сети ваши, то в загрузочном скрипте им можно загрузить свою переменную среды, например:

```
setx LOGIN_NAME "v.putin"
```

Тогда в списке вы получите переменную `LOGIN_NAME` или напрямую `System.getenv("LOGIN_NAME")`

Comment: Я так понимаю, автор хочет получить имя клиента, который подключился к приложению.

Comment: он может хотеть все что угодно, но набор получаемых им параметров очень ограничен (см. мой ответ)

Comment: Прочитал Ваш комментарий, затем перечитал ответ и еще раз вопрос. И ничего не понял. Автор пишет что `System.getenv()` не годится, потому что эта ф-я возвращает переменные окружения того контекста в котором ранится само приложение. А ему нужно знать логин нейм удаленного пользователя, обращающегося к приложению. Но Вы говорите что "он может хотеть всё что угодно" :) Но мы же тут решаем ту проблему которая автору кажется важной.